# userEvent in React Testing Library Doesn't Cause onClick To Be Called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to run a really simple test with react-testing-library where a button is given a mock function, the button is clicked, and the test checks that the function was called. However, the test is currently failing because the function isn't being called. Here's the code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

describe('Button', () => {
  test('eventHandler called on click', () => {
    const handleClick = jest.fn();
    render(
      <button onClick={handleClick} type="button">
        Click Me
      </button>
    );

    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'));

    expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

No errors are thrown, the button is successfully found, but for some reason, the function doesn't register that it's been called.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Exact same issue and effective v.14 all api's are async - https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/pull/790

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem, fireEvent works but the recommended userEvent doesn't trigger click handler. Turned out that userEvent is async. Below is my working test case.

```
test('Error message should show when all fields are blank', async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup()
  render(<Signup />)
  
  await user.click(screen.getByRole('button'))

  expect(screen.getByTestId('errors'))
    .toHaveTextContent(dict.fields_must_not_be_empty)
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I noticed this wasn't a problem when my app was on react scripts 4 and react 17 but became a problem after upgrading.

Comment: Exact same issue - this works great.

Comment: Effective v.14 all api's are async - https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/pull/790

Answer (score 3):

Worked fine for me
Make sure you install this package @testing-library/user-event @testing-library/dom

Steps:

1. npx create-react-app rtl-typescript --template typescript
2. npx install --save-dev @testing-library/user-event @testing-library/dom

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

describe('Button', () => {
  test('eventHandler called on click', () => {
    const handleClick = jest.fn();
    render(
      <button onClick={handleClick} type="button">
        Click Me
      </button>
    );

    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'));

    expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

[image]

In case needed, my package.json file dependencies

[image]

Comment: This is a better answer, is more detailed than the others.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
describe('Button', () => {
  test.only('eventHandler called on click', () => {
    const handleClick = jest.fn();
    render(
      <button onClick={handleClick} type="button">
        Click Me
      </button>
    );

    userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Click me/i));

    expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

add a `role` tag to your button

```
<button 
  onClick={handleClick} 
  role="button" 
  type="button"
>
  Click Me
</button>
```

or use `screen.getByText('Click Me')`

Comment: Doesn't seem to do it. The test is able to find the button successfully but for some reason the `userEvent.click` doesn't trigger the onClick prop

Comment: Did you install userEvent?

Comment: Yeah, and running other userEvent tests pass (like the one from the docs - https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event#clickelement-eventinit-options)