# React testing library failing but I'm sure the code is correct

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to learn react-testing-library but I have a failure here that I'm sure should work and can't find the error.

It's a simple name and email app where you add a name and email and it is added to a list.

The home has a UserFrom and UserList
"use client"

```
import UserForm from './components/UserForm'
import { useState } from 'react'
import UserList from './components/UserList'

export interface User{
  name: string,
  email: string
}

export default function Home() {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([])

  const onUserAdd = (user:User) => {
    setUsers([...users, user])
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>RTL App</h1>
      <UserForm onUserAdd={onUserAdd}/>
      <hr />
      <UserList users={users}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

User Form take the name and email and passed it back to home

```
"use client"
import React, { useState } from 'react'


const UserForm = ({ onUserAdd }: any) => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [name, setName] = useState('')

    const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        onUserAdd({ name, email })
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input id="email" type="text" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
            </div>
            <button>Add User</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default UserForm
```

UserList then displays the name and email

```
"use client"
import React from 'react'

const UserList = ({users}:any) => {

    const renderUsers = users.map((user:any) => {
        return(
            <tr key={user.name}>
                <td>{user.name}</td>
                <td>{user.email}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    })

  return (
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {renderUsers}
        </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

export default UserList
```

The test are simply to test there are two inputs and a button and test the Useradd function and that the name and email are passed

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import UserForm from './UserForm'

test('it show two inputs and a button', () => {
    render(<UserForm />);
    const inputs = screen.getAllByRole('textbox');
    const button = screen.getByRole('button');

    expect(inputs).toHaveLength(2);
    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
});

test('it calls onUserAdd when form submitted', () => {
    const mock = jest.fn();

    render(<UserForm onUserAdd={mock} />);
    const nameInput = screen.getByRole('textbox', { name: /name/i });
    const emailInput = screen.getByRole('textbox', { name: /email/i });
    userEvent.type(nameInput, 'jane');
    userEvent.type(emailInput, 'jane@jane.com');
    const button = screen.getByRole('button');
    userEvent.click(button);

    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'jane', email: 'jane@jane.com' });
});
```

The error I get says the mock function isn't called but I can't work out why.

Can anyone see what I'm missing

✓ it show two inputs and a button (84 ms)
✕ it calls onUserAdd when form submitted (41 ms)

● it calls onUserAdd when form submitted

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0

  23 |     userEvent.click(button);
  24 |
> 25 |     expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
     |                  ^
  26 |     expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'jane', email: 'jane@jane.com' });
  27 | });
  28 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `@testing-library/user-event` version >= 14, please use `await` before any API. There are some examples on official [doc](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/convenience)

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import UserForm from './UserForm';

test('it show two inputs and a button', () => {
    render(<UserForm />);
    const inputs = screen.getAllByRole('textbox');
    const button = screen.getByRole('button');

    expect(inputs).toHaveLength(2);
    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
});

test('it calls onUserAdd when form submitted', async () => {
    const mock = jest.fn();

    render(<UserForm onUserAdd={mock} />);
    const nameInput = screen.getByRole('textbox', { name: /name/i });
    const emailInput = screen.getByRole('textbox', { name: /email/i });
    await userEvent.type(nameInput, 'jane');
    await userEvent.type(emailInput, 'jane@jane.com');
    const button = screen.getByRole('button');
    await userEvent.click(button);

    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'jane', email: 'jane@jane.com' });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/77369394/UserForm.test.tsx
  ✓ it show two inputs and a button (54 ms)
  ✓ it calls onUserAdd when form submitted (112 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.266 s, estimated 7 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package version:

```json
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
```

Related question: [userEvent in React Testing Library Doesn't Cause onClick To Be Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69300723/userevent-in-react-testing-library-doesnt-cause-onclick-to-be-called)